# Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers (recursion)

Tags: c++, recursion, numbers, set

I'm taking a discrete mathematics course, and I'm required to develop a c++ program which receives a string as an input and returns which natural number (if any) it represents. Natural numbers are defined as follows:
0 = {}, 1 = {{}}, 2 = { {} {{}} }, 3 = { {} {{}} {{} {{}}} } and so on. I'm thinking this can be done recursively with the base case being "{}", but I'm not sure about how to go about thinking about the solution. A friend of mine told me that he has noticed that the number of open braces are always 2^n, but I feel it's just not that simple as this has some issues, I think.
Thank you!

Comment: If you are guaranteed that the input string is well-formed (actually does represent a number), then counting braces should be sufficient. If you need to also detect and reject invalid input, then indeed it's not that simple.

Comment: Strip outer braces. Split the string into "elements" (sequences where opening and closing braces balance out). In a well-formed string, the first element must be `{}`, and each subsequent element is a concatenation of all prior elements, surrounded by an extra pair of braces.

Comment: Notice that the number n is just the set containing 0 through n-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just counting open braces won't distinguish well-formed inputs from malformed inputs.

Start by writing a program that can construct and output a brace-string form number given an input value.

That will clarify the problem for you. Then can you match a brace-string input against one of your constructed brace strings? Can you go from there to the full solution?

**Edit:** The above problem-solving technique is to first solve a simpler subproblem or related problem. Another technique is to look for multiple approaches, then pick one (and be prepared to switch if it turns out to be difficult).

A different approach to this problem is to read the input into an STL set of sets. Something like:

```
class Set {
  std::set<Set> elements;
 public:
  void read(std::istream in) {...}  // recursively reads & adds Sets
  int size() {...}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant. Is it that I should construct a program that does the opposite? receives a number and outputs the set form? Please clarify just a bit :)

Comment: Yes. First write a program that does the opposite. Constructing a string is easier than parsing one, and yet it still does the same recursion.

Comment: Ohhh I got it now! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: Cool! If you get stuck, I added a second way to think about the problem.